Syntax Error Using Double Quoted String and Fat Comma with map
I have a syntax error in a Perl script that I don't understand:
# map BLOCK LIST
map { "/$_" => 1 } qw(foo bar baz);   # syntax error at .. line 1, near "} qw(foo bar baz)"

I have to rewrite it like this:
map { '/' . $_ => 1 } qw(foo bar baz);  # no error

This piece of code works on the other hand:
# Hash reference.
{ "/$_" => 1 };

I am using Perl 5.34.0.

This is a minimal example that reproduces the problem. In my script, I use the returned list.

Try putting a semicolon after opening curly brace.
I'd stick with . $_ though.
From perlfunc on map:

"{" starts both hash references and blocks, so "map { ..." could be
either the start of map BLOCK LIST or map EXPR, LIST.  Because Perl
doesn't look ahead for the closing "}" it has to take a guess at which
it's dealing with based on what it finds just after the "{".  Usually
it gets it right, but if it doesn't it won't realize something is
wrong until it gets to the "}" and encounters the missing (or
unexpected) comma.  The syntax error will be reported close to the "}"

I'd recommend reading on it.

You mean an expression or a block, right? But { "/$_" => 1 } is both a valid block and a valid expression.

From perlfunc on map:
"{" starts both hash references and blocks, so "map { ..." could be either the start of map BLOCK LIST or map EXPR, LIST.  Because Perl doesn't look ahead for the closing "}" it has to take a guess at which it's dealing with based on what it finds just after the "{".  Usually it gets it right, but if it doesn't it won't realize something is wrong until it gets to the "}" and encounters the missing (or unexpected) comma.  The syntax error will be reported close to the "}"
There are also some examples in the man perlfunc. I'd recommend to read it.

@Moses Use the "Edit" to add information to your answer. You've got the right information, just put it together in the right place.

And I thought that I would know everything about map(). ;) I should have scrolled down to the end of perldoc -f map.

Re "And I thought that I would know everything about map()", Did you know that you can use parens around the arguments, even if using map BLOCK? Valid: map( { ... } ... )

Nowadays I always do map( (EXPR), LIST )
